# Mass email service without "watermark"

Tags: email, bulk-email

I have to send large number of emails every month. Is there a service I can use to help me do that?

I am not concerned about the cost. The only thing I am concerned about is that the emails should not have "watermarks" (or banners from the service I am using). I tried MailChimp and several other mass email services but they all seem to include their banners indicating that the emails were sent using some email service.

In other words, every email should look like it is sent from a human user.

I am a PHP developer myself and my first approach was developing a mass emailer myself, but according to the first answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly) it seems very very hard to do it yourself.

So, is there an already existing mass emailing service that would let me do that kind of thing?

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board and requesting tools, library's, resources, software and services are considered off topic. To avoid further disappointment please check out our [help center](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help), additional you could use our [chat channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) to ask questions that are not allowed on the main site, I've left you my opinion on a service you should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used MadMimi (https://madmimi.com/short_ref/z7X) for about 5 years for my ecommerce businesses and clients businesses as well. I've been happy with their service and pricing tiers are much more reasonable than the other services like MailChimp.

I use the "Custom HTML" email option, I do not use their email builder tool. This allows me to have full-control of the email. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Are you sure there will be no "via madmimi.com" or "Powered by Mad Mimi ®"? I haven't tried the Custom HTML version yet because it requires payment. Please tell me you are 100% positive there will be no sign of it being a mass email :)

Comment: Adnan, I just looked at my last email that was sent and I can tell you there is not a "powered by" in the email content or "via" in the email header. If you have link tracking enabled, then the links are pointing to go.madmimi.com, but this can be resolved... 1) Sign-up for Custom Domain in the "Add things" section. 2)

Comment: 2) Disable link tracking when sending email. They do require an "Unsubscribe" link in all outgoing email in order to conform to the CAN-SPAM law.  In my emails I have done this with custom html which consists of just the link "Unsubscribe". Let me know if you have any questions.